# Error en código RStudio Cloud read.table - no lines available in input

Tags: r, rstudio, table, cloud, read

Estoy haciendo una tarea para la cual necesito usar datos del paquete "AtmChile". No tengo problema al instalarlo, pero a la hora de ejecutar el código:

```
data <-ChileAirQuality(Comunas = c("AH", "EB"), Parametros = c("PM10", "PM25", "CO", "NOX", "NO2", "NO", "O3", "SO2", "temp" , "ws" , "wd"), fechadeInicio = "01/01/2020", fechadeTermino = "31/12/2020", Site = TRUE)
```

Me tira el error:

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
> no lines available in input
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(file, "rt") :
> file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using the former

Este problema solo me pasa en el RStudio Cloud, pero en la versión offline de R no me aparece.
¿Alguien sabe qué podría estar pasando? Gracias.

Comment: No tengo una solución, pero quizás esto te ayude a identificar el problema. En mi instalación local de R en Fedora Linux tengo el mismo mensaje de error. rstudio.cloud también usa Linux, ese podría ser el problema. Generalmente las librerías de R son multiplataforma, pero puede haber problemas por dependencias externas, codificación de caracteres o cosa por el estilo.  Para verificar ¿la versión offline que usas es en Windows? ¿Qué versión de R usas? ¿Qué versión de la librería usas, la de CRAN o la GitHUb? En mi caso es la 0.21 de CRAN.

Comment: Con la información que tengo no estoy seguro, pero por lo que veo parece que es un bug de la librería que no está testeada en Linux (hasta ahora es el único elemento común en el problema). Quizás podamos ayudar al desarrollador abriendo un incidente en el repositorio para que lo corrija. Quedo pendiente para colaborar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en línea 52 de la función `ChileAirQuality`. Aquí está
el código: https://github.com/franciscoxaxo/AtmChile/blob/main/R/ChileAirQuality.R

En esa línea se busca al archivo `SINCA.CSV` para leer luego algunas cosas desde ahí. El dichoso archivo está en la librería y se llama `SINCA.csv`. El problema es que en Linux los nombres archivo son sensibles a mayúsculas, busca `SINCA.CSV` y no lo encuentra. En Windows sí porque `csv` y `CSV` son equivalentes. rstudio.cloud funciona sobre Linux, por eso el error.

Solución 1:

Después de cargar la librería y antes de usarla correr la siguiente línea desde la consola:

```
body(ChileAirQuality)[[2]] <- substitute(sysEstaciones   <- system.file("/extdata/SINCA.csv", package = "AtmChile", mustWork = TRUE))
```

Es una forma bastante rudimentaria de cambiar una línea de código en una función que está cargada en el entorno. Básicamente cambia lo era la línea 52 del código con una expresión nueva en la que se corrige el nombre del archivo y se agrega el `mustWork = TRUE` para que de un error si no encuentra el archivo. Como está en el paquete regresa una cadena de caracteres vacía, el problema pasa a la función siguiente que es la que da el error y está fuera de contexto.

Solución 2.

Abrir un incidente en el repositorio y pedir a quién mantiene el paquete que lo corrija, indicando claramente el problema y la solución propuesta.